# How to integrate firebase functions into devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure, google-cloud-platform, cicd

I have a project which has `firebase functions`

From my local I can run `firebase deploy --only functions` and it will build and deploy firebase functions to firebase.

Now I want to enable CICD via Azure Devops.
So I need to build the functions in CI and get the build artifact in CD to deploy it to different firebase project (as different environments).

The problem is building and deploying is done in the same time via `firebase deploy`

I googled a lot not able to find a solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

As build artifact you need to publish, `firebase.json`, `.firebaserc` and whole `functions` folder including `package.json` (without `node_modules`)

Then in release using `sudo firebase deploy --token $(firebase-token) --project $(firebase-project) --only functions --force`